# Finding time complexity between shortest path in Dynamic Programming and Brute Force

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, shortest-path, brute-force

What is the difference between shortest path in Dynamic Programming and Brute Force?
What is the time complexity in between two of them?
How to implement both algorithms in java?

Comment: can you please add what you have tried so far? Adhere to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines to ask question properly.

Comment: Once you jave a sample of both you can calculate the O(x) for both